# Совпадают кластеры FAT для файлов

Tags: dos

У меня есть два загрузочных img MS-DOS 2.0 - один оригинальный img, другой img сделал я при помощи программы imdisk.exe. Оба img 360K floppy. Оба img загружаются в VirtualBox и работают. Я сравнивал кластеры FAT для системных файлов в обеих img, вот результат:

```
original img IBMBIO.COM     2,3,4,5,6,255,EOF
my img IMBBIO.COM       2,3,4,5,6,255,EOF

original img IBMDOS.COM     7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,EOF
my img IBMDOS.COM       7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,EOF

origianl img COMMAND.COM    63,EOF
my img COMMAND.COM      24,25,10,11,12,13,14,15,EOF
```

Как видно в моем img для файлов IBMDOS.COM И COMMAND.COM кластеры 10,11,12,13,14,15 совпадают, значит вывод получается два файла занимают одни и те же кластеры FAT и на диске. Не смотря на это мой img прекрасно загружается и работает в VirtualBox. Так же для COMMAND.COM в оригинальном img только один кластер, в моем их 8 - почему не понятно. Я заметил что маркер конца файла который делает программа imdisk.exe для своих создаваемых img - просто 0x0 а не как должно быть 0x0FF8.

Как я сделал мой образ img - взял загрузочный сектор из оригинального img, взял системные файлы MS-DOS из оригинального img, при помощи imdisk.exe сделал свой img, то есть реконструировал оригинальный img.

Я выкладываю свою программу для просмотра кластеров FAT, может я где то ошибся. Почему кластеры FAT для IBMDOS.COM И COMMAND.COM в моем img совпадают, может это ошибка в моей программе?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BYTE *buff = NULL;

short int file_1_sectors[100000];

void get_file_sectors_from_fat(short int first)
{
    BYTE * fat = buff + 512;

    bool end_of_file = false;

    short int sect_offset = 0;
    short int clast_num = first;

    int index = 0;

    do {
    
        file_1_sectors[index++] = clast_num;

        sect_offset = (clast_num * 3) / 2;
        
        int short even_or_odd = (clast_num * 3) % 2;

        clast_num = fat[sect_offset];

        if(even_or_odd == 0) //if even 0
        {
            clast_num = clast_num & 0x0FFF;
        }
        else //if odd 1
        {
            clast_num = clast_num >> 4;
        }

        //if(clast_num > 0x0FF8 )
        //  break;

        //for img files EOF = 0
        if( clast_num == 0 )
            break;


        
    } while ( 1 );
}

bool compare_names(char * filename, BYTE * root)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
    {
        if(filename[i] != root[i])
            return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

int get_first_sector_from_root_dir(char * filename)
{
    //calculate start offset of root dir
    BYTE * root = buff + 0xA00; //320K diskette 5 * 512
    //BYTE * root = buff + 19 * 512;    //1440K diskette

    //112d = 70h = num dir entires 320K diskette
    //each entry = 32 bytes

    for ( int i = 0; i < 112; i++ )
    {
        if(compare_names(filename, root))
        {
            short int first_sector = *(root + 26);

            //file found return first cluster in FAT
            return first_sector;
        }

        //next root dir entry
        root += 32;
    }

    //file not found
    return -1;
}


int main (void)
{

    FILE *fp;
    
    
    
    fopen_s(&fp, "msdos2.img", "rb");   //360K img
    //fopen_s(&fp, "Disk01.img", "rb");     //360K img
    

    UINT n_seek_pos = 0;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    
    DWORD dwFileSize = ftell(fp);

    rewind(fp);

    buff = new BYTE[dwFileSize];

    fread((BYTE*)buff, dwFileSize, 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    
    //short int first = get_first_sector_from_root_dir("IBMBIO  COM");
    //short int first = get_first_sector_from_root_dir("IBMDOS  COM");
    short int first = get_first_sector_from_root_dir  ("COMMAND COM");
    
    if(first != -1 )
    {
        get_file_sectors_from_fat(first);

        short int * debug = &file_1_sectors[0];
    }

    delete [] buff;

    //MessageBox(NULL, "Done!", "INFO", MB_OK);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *origianl img COMMAND.COM 63,EOF* А какого он размера? *для COMMAND.COM в оригинальном img только один кластер* ?? Вы же сами показываете, что два.

Comment: Смотрел Свойства COMMAND.COM в Проводнике Windows 15 480 байт размер (не на диске размер, как есть в байтах). Размер сектора на флоппи 512 Байт, получается в FAT COMMAND.COM должен занимать приблизительно 30 кластеров (30 секторов на диске).